# SAS - creating macros dynamically

Tags: dynamic, macros, sas, nested

I would like to dynamically create macros to query a transactional data set. I have a table that has a set of parameters (**parameter_data**) and transaction data (**txs**). For each row in my parameter data I want to create a macro that can be called to query the data.

Parameter data:

```
data parameter_data;
input macro_name $ parameter_name $ parameter_value $;
datalines;
A Person_ID 1
B TX_ID 2
;
```

Transactional Data:

```
data txns;
input Person_ID $ TX_ID $ TX_Amount $;
datalines;
John Sales 1123
Mary Acctng 34
John Sales 23
Mary Sales 2134
;
```

Here I try to create a macro that should create macros dynamically according to the parameter data. The 'inner macros' are the macros that are created from the parameter data.

```
%macro outerMacro;

/*loop through each row in the parameter table to get the detail of the macro we want to create*/
%DO ROW = 1 %To 2;
data _NULL_;
set parameter_data;
if _N_ = ROW then do;
    call symputx('parameter_name',parameter_name);
    call symputx('parameter_value',parameter_value);
    end;
run;

/*define inner macro parameters*/
%let macroName = myMacro; /*set the name of the macro we want to create*/
%let innerMacroStart = macro &macroName.; /*set the macro name to start the macro definition*/
%let innerMacroEnd = mend &macroName;

%&&innerMacroStart.; /*start the inner macro*/

    /*body of the macro*/
    data output;
    set txns;
    &&parameter_name = &&parameter_value; 
    /*so here effectively for the first row in the parameter table we are filtering where person_id = John*/
    run;

%&&innerMacroEnd.; /*end the inner macro*/

%mend outerMacro;

%&&outerMacroName.;
```

It seems that SAS is unable to parse the lines %innerMacroStart. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: As you need to deal with variable parameters, have you considered a `PARMBUFF`-style macro? 
https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/macro/z0206961.htm

Comment: Welcome and thanks for giving an explanation and providing what you have attempted. (1) Does the table just contain values that the inner macro needs to test / use (i.e. no SAS code, per se)? (2) Does the inner macro have the same template / structure every time? From what has been presented, I think this should be achievable by the use of `call execute` or writing the macro definition out to a file and then using `%include` to invoke it.

Comment: agreed with @Amir - much better to write this to a file and %include it, that way you can also debug much more easily (just look at the generated file)

Comment: @amir please see my update above.

To answer your questions:

1) Table x contains the parameters that define what the inner macro needs to filter on
2) Table x has the same structure always – it is read in from a flat file.

Comment: @amir could you elaborate on the %include method or post a link? Thanks for the input.

Comment: Please update your question to include some sample input and output data, both for the parameters and what you're querying.

Comment: At the moment, I couldn't find a link to such an example, but the syntax for `%include` is documented [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000214504.htm). Question (3) If each observation from data set x is supposed to supply the parameters for a `where` clause or `if` condition, do you want each inner macro to create SAS statements that generate a new data set or just generate the SAS code for the condition, i.e. a single SAS statement, and nothing else? Perhaps give an example of the SAS statement(s) you want to see generated from inner.

Comment: Question (4) As you want to create macro per observation on data set x and want to be able to invoke any of the generated macros elsewhere, is there a meaningful / useful naming convention for the macros to distinguish them, or will a simple sequential number suffix suffice your needs?

Comment: @amir please see the update to my question. I have reduced it to its more essential problem. (3) I dont want to create data sets, each inner macro creates code for filtering. (4) arbitrary naming convention (1, 2, 3....) would be fine.

Comment: For your example input data please show what it is that you want to generate. Also include an example of how you intend to use the things you have generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is just to subset data then it might be better to generate macro **variables** instead of actual macros. Try something like this instead.

```
data _null_;
  set parameter_data ;
  call symputx(macro_name,catx(' ','where also'
              ,parameter_name,'=',quote(trim(parameter_value)),';'));
run;
```

Then just use the generated where statement(s) when you need them by expanding the macro variable. Like this:

```
data output ;
  set txns;
  &a 
run;
```

If you really want to generate a macro definition then you probably want to just use a data step to write the code to a file and then %include the file to compile the macros.  That will be much easier to debug than macro logic.

Let's fix your parameter file to better match your test data. Person_ID and TX_ID are character variables in your transaction dataset. You will probably need to add logic or change the parameter file to allow it to handle testing of both numeric and character variables.  For now I just made it generate code that assumes that PARAMETER_NAME refers to a character variable so that PARAMETER_VALUE will need to have quotes added to make it a string literal.

```
data parameter_data;
input macro_name :$32. parameter_name :$32. parameter_value $:200.;
datalines;
A Person_ID John 
B TX_ID Acctng 
;

data txns;
input Person_ID $ TX_ID $ TX_Amount $;
datalines;
John Sales 1123
Mary Acctng 34
John Sales 23
Mary Sales 2134
;
```

Now let's run a data step to generate the code for all of your macros. I added logic to use `AND` if there were multiple "parameters" defined for each macro.

```
filename code temp;
data _null_;
  set parameter_data ;
  by macro_name ;
  file code ;
  if first.macro_name then put
  '%macro ' macro_name ';' 
/ 'data output;'
/ '  set txns;'
/ '  where ' @ 
  ;
  else put ' and ' @ ;
  put parameter_name '=' parameter_value :$quote. @ ;
  if last.macro_name then put
  ';'
/ 'run;'
/ '%mend ' macro_name ';'
  ;
run;
```

Now just use %include to compile the macros.

```
%include code / source2 ;

NOTE: %INCLUDE (level 1) file CODE is file C:\...\#LN00048.
432  +%macro A ;
433  +data output;
434  +  set txns;
435  +  where Person_ID ="John" ;
436  +run;
437  +%mend A ;
438  +%macro B ;
439  +data output;
440  +  set txns;
441  +  where TX_ID ="Acctng" ;
442  +run;
443  +%mend B ;
NOTE: %INCLUDE (level 1) ending.
```

Now you can use your macros.

```
445   options mprint;
446   %a ;
MPRINT(A):   data output;
MPRINT(A):   set txns;
MPRINT(A):   where Person_ID ="John" ;
MPRINT(A):   run;

NOTE: There were 2 observations read from the data set WORK.TXNS.
      WHERE Person_ID='John';
NOTE: The data set WORK.OUTPUT has 2 observations and 3 variables.

447   %b ;
MPRINT(B):   data output;
MPRINT(B):   set txns;
MPRINT(B):   where TX_ID ="Acctng" ;
MPRINT(B):   run;

NOTE: There were 1 observations read from the data set WORK.TXNS.
      WHERE TX_ID='Acctng';
NOTE: The data set WORK.OUTPUT has 1 observations and 3 variables.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have placed a comment before each block of code, but essentially it is:

1. Parameter set up.
2. Macro generation.
3. %include.
4. Call any desired macro.

I have assumed no more than 999 parameter observations - this is controlled by `seq`.

You can examine file "inner_macro.sas" to see the macro definitions.

**NB.** When you try it, make sure to use your own path in place of `<your-path>` (occurs twice):

```
/* set up parameters */
data parameters;
   infile datalines dlm=',';

   input var      : $8.
         operator : $8.
         value    : $8.
   ;

   datalines;
name,eq,"John"
age,gt,12
weight,eq,0
;

/* read parameters and generate a macro definition for each obs, written to a file */
data _null_;
   file '<your-path>/inner_macro.sas';

   set parameters;

   seq = put(_n_,z3.);

   put '%macro inner_' seq ';';
   put '    where ' var operator value ';';
   put '%mend inner_' seq ';';
   put;
run;

/* %include (submits code in file) all of the macro definitions */
%include '<your-path>/inner_macro.sas';

options mprint;

/* invoke the macro with the required data sets */
data class1;
   set sashelp.class;
   %inner_001;
run;

data class2;
   set sashelp.class;
   %inner_002;
run;

data class3;
   set sashelp.class;
   %inner_003;
run;
```